# Erase matrix element and give it new size and elements in rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Example in R:

```
A: a = matrix(1:100,10,10)

B: a = matrix(1:9,3,3)

C: a = matrix(1:400,20,20)
```

What is the equivalent rcpp code for this simple example?

`a` is always one variable with mutable contents and size.

In A, I created the matrix a with this rcpp code:

```
NumericMatrix a(10,10)
```

And fill it with sequence of number from 1 to 100.
I want to resize this matrix with a command like this:

```
a(3,3)
```

or

```
a(20,20)
```

and put 1 to 9 or 1 to 400 in it.

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking. What do try to do in Rcpp? and what have you tried? I vote to close it as unclear question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. **The question is clear now:** You want to resize an existing `NumericMatrix` object from the Rcpp library. I don't know the answer, but I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Much clearer now. Has my reopen vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RcppArmadillo can solve the problem:

```
arma::mat m1 = arma::eye<arma::mat>( 10, 10 ) ;

m1.set_size(20,20);
m1.set_size(3,3);
```

I do not know if it is possible in rcpp.

Comment: Any recent development on that? Is it possible to resize a NumericMatrix? Thanks.